# ASP Redirect Not Working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

I am new to asp.net. Is there any obvious reason why this isnt working?

```
<%

If Request.Url.ToString.ToLower.IndexOf("http://www.secondarydomain.com") > -1 Then
    Server.Transfer("secure/login.aspx")
Else
    Response.Redirect("index.php")

End If

%>
```

What I need is for it to redirect to "secure/login.aspx" when the user visits www.secondarydomain.com and for it to redirect to index.php when the user vists www.primarydomain.com

At the moment, www.secondarydomain.com works correctly but www.primarydomain.com says "The page isn't redirecting properly"

Contents of Global.asax

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.vb" Inherits="CompanyLogin.Global" %>
```

Error given by Chrome:

```
The webpage at http://primarydomain.com/index.php has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.

Error code: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

Also, I am not sure if this would cause a problem but the index.php file is for a WordPress installation and here is the contents of the WordPress .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Screenshot of FireFox console when trying to access www.primarydomain.com:

[image: redirect_console]

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error you get?, to be honest *"The page isn't redirecting properly"* is about as generic as they come.

Comment: is that all in you global file. no redirection on Application start or session start?  If thats not the case please try resetting the Cookies and check.

Comment: @Lankymart I will get the actual error.

Comment: @KrunalPatil That is everything in the global file. I will try resetting cookies again.

Comment: Resetting cookies didnt work. I have added the error and the contents of the .htaccess file to my question.

Comment: By the way are your cookies enabled for your application ?

Comment: @KrunalPatil How do I check this?

Comment: follow these steps in url : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-and-disable-cookies-website-preferences

Comment: @KrunalPatil Followed those steps but unfortunately I am still getting the same result.

Comment: are you using any of these plugins disable-canonical-redirects.php or
WPML plugin.

Comment: @KrunalPatil I am not using either of those plugins but I am using this plugin: Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin - 
However, there is no redirect set up for the home page of the website.

Comment: sorry buddy I think I'm out of my solutions. But will try to dig in more into this and get back to you later.

Comment: @KrunalPatil No problem, that would be great. Thank you very much for your time and help so far :)

Comment: Your code is working as you can see from the error `http://primarydomain.com/index.php` is being loaded but something else is then forcing it to redirect again (possibly in the php code?) which is giving you a redirect loop (this is bad). Might be worth a read - [What Causes A Redirect Loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260028/what-causes-a-redirect-loop).

Answer (score 0):

It should be http://www.website.com instead of website.com.

Comment: What should be? Sorry but how does that help?, the OP is using `.IndexOf()` which finds any occurrence of `website.com`, so looking for `http://www.website.com` isn't going to make a difference.